# How do I change this php code to show a image instead of the text?

Tags: php, facebook

I have this line of code, it works fine.  But instead of showing the text 'Login via Facebook'  I want to show the the facebook connect button (image).  How do I do that?

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="aw_fb_login(); return false;"><?php echo $this->helper('fbintegrator')->__('Login via Facebook'); ?></a><li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with this and go from there:

```
helper('fbintegrator')->__('<img src="/path/to/facebookConnect.png" />');
```

Comment: hey AlienWebguy - that worked perfectly thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="aw_fb_login(); return false;">
 <?php echo helper('fbintegrator')->__('<img src="/path/to/image.png" alt=""/>'); ?>
</a><li>
```